# Values for which system has infinite many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've seen many similar examples on the site but are still a bit unsure about this one.

$$x + 2y + 3z = 4$$
$$x + ky + 4z = 6$$
$$x + 2y + (k + 2)z = 6.$$

After some reduction I've figured the following row is the only relevant one.
[0 0 (k - 1) 2]

For a unique solution k should not equal 1.
For no solution there is no value of k.
For infinitely many solutions k = 1.

Am I right?

Edit: Made a mistake, for no solution k = 1 for infinitely many solutions there is no solution of k.

Comment: Think of your last row as (k-1)z=2. If k=1, you get 0=2. For k\neq1 you get z=2/(k-1). Then, how many solutions does each case give?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor I've edited my post. Made a typing error. I think I have it now. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if $k=2$? There’s more than one “relevant” row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Delta=1\cdot k\cdot(k+2)+1\cdot2\cdot3+1\cdot2\cdot4-1\cdot k\cdot3-1\cdot4\cdot2-1\cdot2\cdot(k+2)=$$
$$=k^2-3k+2=(k-1)(k-2),$$

$$\Delta_x=4\cdot k\cdot(k+2)+6\cdot2\cdot4+3\cdot6\cdot2-6\cdot k\cdot3-4\cdot4\cdot2-6\cdot2\cdot(k+2)=$$
$$=2(k-2)(2k-7),$$
$$\Delta_y=1\cdot6\cdot(k+2)+1\cdot3\cdot6+1\cdot4\cdot4-1\cdot6\cdot3-1\cdot4\cdot(k+2)-1\cdot6\cdot4=2(k-2)$$ and
$$\Delta_z=1\cdot6\cdot k+1\cdot2\cdot6+1\cdot2\cdot4-1\cdot k\cdot4-1\cdot2\cdot6-1\cdot6\cdot2=2(k-2).$$
The system has infinitely many solutions for $$\Delta=\Delta_x=\Delta_y=\Delta_z=0$$ or for $$k=2$$. 
The system has no solutions for $\Delta=0$, but $\Delta_x\neq0$ or $\Delta_y\neq0$ or $\Delta_z\neq0$,

which happens for $k=1$.

Comment: Your answer differs from mine in that there is a value for k for which the system has infinitely many solutions, namely, k = 2. I struggle to follow your calculations as I have trained in another method. Perhaps you can clarify if I give you this: First row, [1 2 3 4] second row, [0 (k-2) 1 2] third row, [0 0 (k -1) 2]. Why would it have infinitely many solutions if k = 2?

Comment: @Tightrope For $k=2$ our system it's: $x+2y+3z=4$, $x+2y+4z=6$ and $x+2y+4z=6$. I think now it's clear.